# How can I implement "gzencode"(PHP function) in nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, gzip

I have some API which need the sign with encrypted by [gzencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) function in php, now I need to use nodejs to make a test tools for testing these API.

I've tried `pako` and `zlib` module in nodejs, however, the compress result was always different from php, so I want to know how can I make the same compress result in nodejs like gzencode in php7 ?

```
const pako = require('pako');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const input = '1234';

zlib.gzip(input, (err, buffer) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("--------zlib result---------");
        console.log(buffer.toString());
        console.log("");
        console.log("length: " + buffer.toString().length);
        console.log("md5: " + crypto.createHash('md5').update(buffer.toString()).digest("hex"));
    }
});

var result = pako.gzip(input, { to: 'string' });
console.log("--------pako result---------");
console.log(result);
console.log("");
console.log("length: " + result.length);
console.log("md5: " + crypto.createHash('md5').update(result).digest("hex"));
```

```php
$str = gzencode('1234');
var_dump($str);
var_dump(strlen($str));
var_dump(md5($str));
```

### nodejs result

#### pako result

```
3426 £àã
length: 24
md5: 45461056d1301798aae739d467b1811b
```

#### zlib result

```
3426 ���
length: 23
md5: ea90ab1d16e5596020fb313119879e26<br/>
```

### php result

```
string(24) "3426"
int(24)
string(32) "cbe26958c184e607833efbf9b63516fb"
```

Comment: Strangely enough, if I try getting the md5 of the gzip compressed string in PHP here: [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), I get a result of 376bf38322e70a492fa78479dcc464d8.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the md5 func of php is diffrent between linux and windows, my results are getting from win, and I did get diffrent result with  trying to run in centos. But it's not the point, I need to gzip a str and unzip it in php by using gzdecode. I have not get the right way to gzip the data in nodejs until now, and I want to know "how to gzip a data which could be ungzip in php by using gzdecode"

Comment: Great, thanks @user9442386, this clears things up for me.. I've added an answer, which I believe resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly tricky one to diagnose, but in the end the fix is, thankfully, quite small:

Instead of:

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update(buffer.toString()).digest("hex"));
```

we'll just update with the buffer object itself:

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update(buffer).digest("hex"));
```

So the updated code is:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const input = '1234';

zlib.gzip(input, (err, buffer) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("--------Zlib result---------");
        console.log("buffer (hex): ", buffer.toString("hex"));
        console.log("");
        console.log("length: " + buffer.length);
        console.log("md5: " + crypto.createHash('md5').update(buffer).digest("hex"));
    }
});
```

Now both the Node.js and PHP code produce an md5 output of:

```
cbe26958c184e607833efbf9b63516fb
```

For the input ('1234').

As you noted above, this may be platform dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did help a lot for me